# How do I get a colored sky instead of black for stars photo?

Tags: night, stars

How do I get a colored sky instead of black for stars photo? I recently took a long exposure night shot and it looked great but the sky is basically black with white stars. I've seen some amazing photos online where the sky is very rich in colors. How is that done?

[image]